# Retry failed feature file

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

**Background**
We are able to run `.feature` files in parallel, using `teymyers Cucumber Parallel` plugin. This creates a java file for each `.feature` file, for example, Parallel01IT.java, Parallel02IT.java ...  ...

**Question**: How can run I re-run/retry these ParallexxIT.java files if fails?

There is nothing that comes to me that I can try. I could found few links in SO for Karate Cucumber, Ruby Cucumber but not on Serenity Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

1. While fresh run pass rerun plugin as an argument `"-p", "rerun:target/cucumber/rerun.txt"`. This will generate cucumber
   rerun file which has line numbers of failed scenarios.
2. Then next time instead of features directory pass rerun text file
   `"@target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"`
3. This will re-run only your failed scenarios

If you are using cucumber options [I am not sure but I guess this was planned for deprecation] via junit runner then do as below.

Fresh run :

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
        "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"})
```

Rerun :

```
        @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"@target/cucumber/rerun.txt"},
            plugin = {"pretty", rerun:target/cucumber/rerun.txt"})
```